# Is it possible to validate if a link (or string) matches with any valid Jekyll permalink?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, permalinks, jekyll-extensions

Is it possible to validate if a link (or string) matches with any valid Jekyll permalink?

For example, I'm generating dynamically a navigation bar like this:

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="{{ base }}/{{ site.locale }}/about/the-project/">About</a>
</li>
```

Now, is it possible to know if "{{ base }}/{{ site.locale }}/about/the-project/" is a valid permalink ?

The idea is to skip that 'LI' tag if the link does not match with any valid permalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm using basically what I have for my sitemap.

```
{% assign tmp_posts = site.posts | where:'locale', site.locale %}
{% assign tmp_buildlogs = site.buildlog | where:'locale', site.locale %}
{% assign all_posts = tmp_posts | concat: tmp_buildlogs %}
```

Then, I can just check the links.